# List Embdedding and Defined Property

Tags: python, arrays, list, math, matrix

Suppose I have a matrix.

The question is, how do I show that whether a given list embedded within a list, the following rule is satisfied:

Given any three (or more) members of the list, `X([i][j])[k] = X[i]([j][k])`
?  If you are confused you can think of this in terms of a identity matrix, for instance, the identity matrix is `A= [[1,0],[0,1]]`. The identity does not follow the property because `=(0.0).1 != 0.(0.1)`. Where `(0.0)` means `A[0][0]` and `(0.1)` means `A[0][1]`. So how do I apply the row and column of 1 to the row and column that contains (0.0)?  Note that (0.0) =1 in this case and (0.1) = 0
Well what I have to do is to show that

`A[i][j]*k != i*A[j][k]` but that doesn't really make sense in python because of *.

```
A = [[1,0],[0,1]]

for i in A:
    for j in A:
        for k in A: 
          if A[i][j]*k != i*A[j][k]:
              return print("Property Not Satisfied")
```

Comment: Is the matrix `A` always square?

Comment: What is `(0.0).1` exactly? `(0.0)` means `A[0][0]`, and then how do you apply the remaining `.1` on it?

Comment: That's the question i'm asking. (0.0) = A[0][0]. I want to know if theres a way to apply the remaining 1, which is an entry in the matrix.

Comment: @FatihAkici I want to know a way to do this: X([i][j])[k] = X[i]([j][k])

Comment: I and others can help if we can understand clearly what you want the output to be. So please help me understand - say for i = 0, j = 0, and k = 1, what should A([i][j])[k] be? Let's go step by step. A([0][0]) is 1. So next how should the [k] part be applied? It becomes something like 1[1] at this step, which is meaningless. I am sure you are not formulating your question right.

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to show X[X[i][j]][k] = X[i][X[j][k]]?

Comment: Yes,  that's all that I wanted to show. I just didn't know how to write it that way. HAHA. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

If I have no misunderstanding, you can implement exactly like you said, just compare integer-part, fraction-part separately:

```
def check_matrix(A):
    row, column = len(A), len(A[0])

    for i in range(row):
        for j in range(column):
            # if j out of index in row, skip
            if j >= row:
                break
            for k in range(column):
                # compare integer-part, fraction-part separately
                if A[i][j] != i or k != A[j][k]:
                    print("Property Not Satisfied")
                    print(A[i][j], i, k, A[j][k])
                    return False
    return True

def test():
    A = [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
    check_matrix(A)
```

output:

```
Property Not Satisfied
1 0 0 1
```

Hope that will help you, and comment if you have further questions. : )

Comment: Okay but that's only for the identity matrix, what about for other lists of lists? In General I mean. For instance [[1,3,4,5],[4,5,7,6],[4,3,5,6],[3,2,4,3]] Is there a more general way to do it?

Comment: I want to know a way to see if this holds in a general matrix: X([i][j])[k] = X[i]([j][k])

Comment: sorry, I think I'm totally confused about your requriement.